# SQL query to get list of active customers. Active are those that are in the table at least once each week

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have a table that contains usage data for our customers - customerID, DateofUsage. So any day, the same customerID may occur multiple times.

I want to figure out the list of active Customers. Active are those that have used the product at least once each week.

When I use this :

```
    SELECT distinct [CustomerId], datepart(week, [Date]) FROM CustomerUsage
    group by [subscriptionid]
```

I get a list of CustomerIDs and which week they were used in. I try to extend this by doing this:

```
    SELECT distinct [CustomerId], COUNT(datepart(week, [Date])) FROM CustomerUsage
    group by [subscriptionid]
```

But now the numbers for count is all messed up. I was hoping to get the number of weeks the customer was active in and if that number was greater than the number of weeks so far, I have my list. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: And you've tagged this 'mysql' because?

Comment: Changed the tag to sql.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Azure

Comment: @Anurag This should give you number of  week a cusotmer is active.   select [CustomerId], count(weekactive) from (
SELECT distinct [CustomerId], datepart(week, [Date]) as weekactive FROM CustomerUsage
    group by [subscriptionid]
 
 ) group by [CustomerId]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a distinct before the datepart to ensure that you count only the distinct days that the customer was present in the records. The query that you posted counts every row that the customer was present.

```
SELECT distinct [CustomerId]
     , COUNT(Distinct datepart(week, [Date])) 
FROM CustomerUsage
group by [subscriptionid]
```